# How to pass dynamic as well as static parameters {hybrid field variables and functions} in React function using map?

Tags: reactjs

I want to reuse a react component that has some static as well as some dynamic fields. Here's the static jsx file:

```
const LoginDetails = [
    {
        id:0,
        controlId:"formBasicEmail",
        Label:"Email",
        type:"Email",
        placeholder:"Enter Registered Email",

    },
    {
        id:1,
        controlId:"formBasicPassword",
        Label:"Password",
        type:"password",
        placeholder:"Enter Password",

    }
];
export default LoginDetails;
```

And here's my rendering screen:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ErrorCodes from './ErrorCodes.jsx';
import LoginDetails from './LoginDetails.jsx';


export default function LoginScreen()
{
  const [credentials,setCredentials] = useState({
    "email":"",
    "password":""
  });
  function LoginScreenRenderer(props)
  {
    return <Form.Group key={props.id} autocomplete="off" controlId={props.controlId}>
    <Form.Label>{props.Label}</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type={props.type} placeholder={props.placeholder}
    // value={EmailID}
    // onChange={e=>{setEmailID(e.target.value);
    //   let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    //   if(regex.test(EmailID))
    //   setRegisterar_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[0]);
    //   else
    //   setRegisterar_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[4]);
    // }}
    />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
      {""}
      </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>;
  }
  return(
    <Form className="FormAligner">
    {LoginDetails.map(LoginScreenRenderer)}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

As you can see, I have commented the lines which I want to address dynamically. Basically for the first rendered component, I want to update EmailValue using useState, whereas for the second component I want to render Password value. This is my initial credentials declaration:

```
const [credentials,setCredentials] = useState({
        "email":"",
        "password":""
      });
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Because if I am not able to achieve this then my entire purpose of using map will be defeated. What I want is:

```
// value={EmailID}
        // onChange={e=>{setEmailID(e.target.value);
        //   let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        //   if(regex.test(EmailID))
        //   setRegisterar_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[0]);
        //   else
        //   setRegisterar_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[4]);
        // }}
```

this part should be dynamically picked and updated for the two different textfields.

Comment: Please provide this on codesandbox to make it easier for us to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [prop.type] to dynamically set the value on credentials.

```
const LoginDetails = [
    {
        id:0,
        controlId:"formBasicEmail",
        Label:"Email",
        type:"email",
        placeholder:"Enter Registered Email",

    },
    {
        id:1,
        controlId:"formBasicPassword",
        Label:"Password",
        type:"password",
        placeholder:"Enter Password",

    }
];

function LoginScreenRenderer(props)
  {
    return <Form.Group key={props.id} autocomplete="off" controlId={props.controlId}>
    <Form.Label>{props.Label}</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type={props.type} placeholder={props.placeholder}
     value={credentials[props.type]}
     onChange={e=>{
        if(props.type === 'email'){
           let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
           if(regex.test(e.target.value))
              setRegisterar_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[0]);
           else
              setRegisterar_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[4]);
        }       
        setCredentials({...credentials, [props.type]: e.target.value});
      }
    />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
      {""}
      </Form.Text>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this a better answer. As it stands there’s no way to know if or how this addresses the question.

Comment: sorry I am a bit confused... Where do I define `props.type`? So that it adds up in sync with the other properties?

Comment: The props.type is what you defined in the LoginDetails object. Then in map you can use it to set the state.

Comment: Hmm, i see thank you so much! Got your point now! Thanks a lot for helping out.